# using Facebook Group Page 'Like' in canvas Tab

Tags: facebook, canvas, fbml, facebook-opengraph

Facebook recently [announced](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/407) the ability to link a Like button to a Facebook Page.

I've created a simple canvas application and successfully added a share button using FBML, how ever, i'm now required to insert a 'Like' button also (i know adding a like button is strange when there's a like button at the top of the page, but thats what the client wants!).  As the post mentions, i need to implement the Graph Api which i've done.  I've tested this directly on the Canvas URL which works fine, how ever it doesn't work when loading into a tab - I get the following error:

FBML Error (line 28): illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position

...is this because you can only use FBML (where the body tag is not allowed) and not the Graph Api within a canvas tab??  Is there anything i can do at present?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my Ruby On Rails application and it was down to forgery protection on POST requests.  Once I figured that out the skip_before_filter did the job.  I've read other people having similar problems and them being down to server problems accepting POST requests.  Just a thought to check out.

Answer (score 0):

I just simply took the  tag out leaving:

<html>
<head>
</head>

<div>
stuff here
</div>
</html>

and viola